# PDF Report to Dashboard

Tags: excel, pdf, report, powerbi-desktop

I am just starting with Power BI.

My task is to turn a pdf report in  PowerBI dashboard.

Since in the report there is not a well defined database but rather single excel tables for each visualisation (not related to each other), I wanted to ask for best practice on getting started with this kind of data.

I checked Power BI Report Builder but it is asking for SQL connection which is not my case of data.

Any ideas on how to better approach to this task?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within Power BI Desktop, you can choose the data source for your new file.  Excel is one of the options.  If it is not there as its own icon (labeled Excel), you can find it from the drop-down icon labeled "Get Data".

Within a single .pbix you can have any number of distinct data sources, including individual Excel workbooks.  When you select an Excel workbook as a data source, you will be asked to choose which worksheets or tables you want to import into the model.